# Dihedral group of order 10 in GAP

Tags: group-theory, gap, dihedral-groups

The dihedral group of order $10$ is given by $D_{10} = \langle a,b| a^5 = b^2 = 1, bab^{-1} = a^{-1}\rangle$. Now I need to find all the elements in GAP. But whenever I type `DihedralGroup(10);` in GAP the output show the elements 
$$[\text{<identity> of ...}, f_2, f_2^2, f_2^3, f_2^4, f_1, f_1f_2, f_1f_2^2, f_1f_2^3, f_1f_2^4 ]$$
How do I get the elements in representatives of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Does ShowMultiplicationTable(DihedralGroup(IsFpGroup,10)); help?

Comment: Looks to me like $a=f_2$ and $b=f_1$.

Answer (score 4):

GAP is treating the Dihedral Group as a "pc-group" - this is good for GAP, but when you are just learning group theory it might not be so clear for you :D

Here is one option that might help you. We can just build the group with the presentation/letters exactly as you gave in the question.

```
gap> f:=FreeGroup("a","b");
<free group on the generators [ a, b ]>
gap> g := f/[f.1^5 ,f.2^2, f.2*f.1*f.2^-1*f.1];
<fp group on the generators [ a, b ]>
gap> SetReducedMultiplication(g);
gap> ShowMultiplicationTable(g);
```

We can double check we have the group we think we do...

```
gap> IdGroup(g);
[ 10, 1 ]
gap> IdGroup(DihedralGroup(10));
[ 10, 1 ]
```

Also maybe you want to be able to do some arithmetic in this group, you could do the following:

```
gap> a:=g.1;;
gap> b:=g.2;;
gap> a*b*a;
b
gap> a^2*b*a*b;
a
```

Comment: You also might want to call `SetReducedMultiplication(g);` after creating`g`, that way elements are always represented in unique form when forming arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks I have added this to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I got it.

Comment: @idiot if this has helped please consider marking this as the accepted answer by pressing the tick that appears next to the question.(If you have other answered questions you could do this for them too).